# Best way to refactor more functions in pgadmin

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm new in PostgreSQL, and i was lookinng for a good way to find and replace a word (the name of a function) in multiple functions.

I'm using the latest version of PostgreSQL.

Does someone knows how can I do it in a good manner?

Thanks

Comment: find and replace?..

Comment: Yes sorry, I've corrected the question.

Comment: no,no - there's a tool. press Ctrl+F and see the name "Find and Replace"

Comment: Ok, I already knew it but I was looking for a way to refactor more functions, not one at time

Comment: You should do that in the source code of your functions that is stored in your version control system (git, svn, ...)

Answer (score 1):

pgadmin offers **"Find and Replace"** window for such operations. Staying neutral about the approach (if pgadmin offers - then I can't say it's a bad practice) you can copy all functions definitions from pg_catalog and use this approach for "bulk" object rename inside function bodies. Or select with replace and then run the changed definitions.

Here's why I would recommend not doing this. Let's say you want to change `length(` to `new_length(` in all functions. if you just

```
t=# select proname,replace(prosrc,'length(','new_length(') from pg_proc where prosrc like '%length(%' limit 3;
  proname   |                  replace
------------+--------------------------------------------
 bit_length | select pg_catalog.octet_new_length($1) * 8
 bit_length | select pg_catalog.octet_new_length($1) * 8
 bit_length | select pg_catalog.new_length($1)
(3 rows)
```

As you see you affect more names then just length. Of course you can use `.length(` to avoid `octet_length` and `bit_length`, but there is no guarantee you dont use just `length` in your code (without `pg_catalog.`). and so on and so forth. So if you blindly replace all occurences you risk to brake the code. And if you check them all, you do one by one anyway. So maybe just go through every occurrence and check every one before changing?..

Lastly I'd use `psql` for such work, or at least mix it with pgadmin. As `psql` has a set of meta commands, very useful. Eg function definition can be get by just `sf fn_name`. Running the definition puts it to history, that can be comfortably edited in vim or any other editor and rerun with changed names. (vim offers `:%s/oldname/newname/g` which is same Find and Replace and so on...)